# `:output-dir` is buggy and what is the usage difference between `:dir` and `:output-dir` header arguments?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

The manual says `:dir` is working directory and `:output-dir` is output directory. It is a a bit confusing. If I don't set output dir, shouldn't it generate output files in the working directory?

For example, this works as expected, outputting the figure in `:dir`:

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file demo-ditaa-simpleboxes.png :dir /tmp/
  +---------+
  |         |
  | Foo     |
  |         |
  +----+----+---+
  |Bar |Baz     |
  |    |        |
  +----+--------+
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:/tmp/demo-ditaa-simpleboxes.png]
```

However, in the following example, if I only specify `:dir` but not `:output-dir`, the plot will be saved in the dir of the buffer, not `:dir`.

```
#+begin_src R :results file graphics replace :file demo-r-plot.png :dir ~/work-dir 
  plot(1:10)
#+end_src
```

And for the following example, the `foo/foo.png` isn't created; however, if I delete `DIR` property and let it create attach dir from the ID, `foo.png` is created successfully in the attach dir... It seems `:output-dir` is buggy?

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       20230727T095322.203310
:DIR:      foo
:END:
#+title: abc
#+property: header-args+ :output-dir (org-attach-dir-get-create)

#+begin_src R :results file  graphics :file foo.png
  plot(1:10)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[attachment:foo.png]]
```

by the way, if I set `:output-dir` to some existing relative path like `../foo/spam`, it fails to create `foo.png` too.

My emacs/org version is :

```
Org mode version 9.6.6 (release_9.6.6 @ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org/)
GNU Emacs 29.0.92 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G9323)) of 2023-06-18
```

Comment: What version of Org mode are you running? I run more-or-less latest upstream (Org mode version 9.7-pre (release_9.6.7-566-gdbb391)) and both code block produce their output where `:output-dir` says they should.

Comment: I updated the question and clarified version.

Comment: The versions are recent enough, but I cannot reproduce the problems you are describing: the first three work for me (assuming that `~/work-dir` in the second case and `./foo` in the third case exist as writable directories already).  There are three directories of interest: the directory where the Org mode file lives (in my case, that's `/tmp'  in all cases), the `:dir` directory which becomes the current working directory of the script in the code block and the `:output-dir` which is to be specified relative to the `:dir` directory....

Comment: If the `:dir` directory is not specified then the directory where the Org mode file lives *is* the `:dir` directory. I have not tried the "by the way..." fourth case because I don't know what settings you have. Can you go back and specify the directory of the Org mode file in all cases? And in the last case, provide a complete example that I can cut and paste to try out?